# NSFetchedResultsController won't respond updates to binary attribute

Tags: objective-c, nsfetchedresultscontroller, binary-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have an `NSFetchedResultsController` that is fetching `User` entities from a context. Everything is working fine; changes to `User` objects are recognized by the `fetchedResultsController`, and the `tableView` updates accordingly.

However, each `User` entity has a Binary Data (`NSData`) `picture` attribute. Whenever I change a `User`'s `picture`, `fetchedResultsController` does not pick up any changes.

```
user.picture = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"picture.png"]);
```

I would expect `controllerDidChangeContent:` to be called when a `picture` is changed, but nothing is triggered.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I set the `picture` in a success block from an asynchronous call. I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: How is the picture attribute represented in the underlying model? Is it a persistent or transient attribute? Is it declared as a binary type or something else? And how are you changing the value - Are you using normal core data semantics to make sure your changes trigger the correct core data setters?

Comment: What happens if you specify Transformable instead of Binary Data? You can read up on how to use Transformable in the Apple Xcode Reference : Core Data Programming Guide.

Comment: @tim The picture attribute is stored as persistent binary data. To set the picture, I am calling `[self setPicture:image]`. @matt Transformable was also not working for me, but it does allow me to store UIImage in core data instead of binary data. I could extend `didChangeValueForKey:` on the `User` object and call a delegate method, maybe that will do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

By default an NSFetchRequest returns a `NSArray`, not a `NSMutableArray`.  Make sure your array type is `NSMutableArray` and then use the line below for your fetchRequest.

`NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];`

This and more information can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/05_Fetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008305-CH107-SW2).

Comment: This doesn't actually answer my question. Maybe my question isn't clear. I'm asking why the `fetchedResultsController` doesn't pick up changes to NSData fields, it shouldn't have anything to do with `NSArray`, `NSMutableArray`, or `executeFetchRequest:`.